# Issues running jhipster

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

please i recently got to know about jhipster, and ever since i have tried creating a project with it, it has never created successfully, it gives me this cb() never called error, this is the screenshot of what i get, please i will appreciate a hand, its really a stress free tool to use and am trying to start using it...
[image]

[image]

So after i updated my npm, i tried it again and again i ran into some errors, i restarted my system, then i went to the project directory and ran npm install, and the first message i got was "The package-lock.json file was created with an older version of npm, so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry, this is a one time fix, please be patient... "
And after a while got some errors but the application came up, i wanted to ask on how to resolve those issues before going on, thanks atomfrede, this are the screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please let me know what i can do to get rid of these errors...
Thanks

Comment: Weird. Which version of node are you running? What does `node -version` print?

Comment: the node version am running on is v14.17.3 and the npm version is 6.14.13... This has been going on for a while now, even before i started using this version of nodejs

Comment: Can you update to npm 7? Maven uses an own node/npm version which is npm 7. If the package.lock file has been generated with npm 7 and you use npm 6 to start the development server that might result in some issues.

Comment: Ok I will do that and get back to you, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help atomfrede, i have edited my post, please check, thanks